# Hadoop as document store database

Tags: hadoop

We have a large document store currently running at 3TB in space and it increments by 1 TB every six months. They are currently stored in a windows file system which has at times caused problems in terms of access and retrieval. We are looking to exploit a Hadoop based document store database. Is it a good idea to go ahead with Hadoop? Anyone has any exposure to the same? What can be the challenges, technology roadblocks in achieving the same?

Comment: I'm curious about what advantages you see in Hadoop for this usage.

Comment: @Msdnexpert: what kind of functionality are you looking for? Simple shared storage? HDFS/Hadoop is not a SAN. More details, please.

Comment: Yes Im looking to leverage HDFS as a distributed scalable storage system. Is that possible?

Comment: Ive examined other options such as using a Document Management System. However Im looking for open source options and came across HDFS?

Comment: Take a look at MongoDB's GridFS (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS). You still didn't answer my question tho. What kind of functionality are you looking for? Does it need to be accessible over a LAN or a public network? What kind of access do you need to the files? HTTP?

Comment: Accessibility is via a public network. The documents would hardly ever be updated. So its like write once read always

Comment: Sounds to me like you're looking for a CDN with a nice interface to handle purging/invalidation. You're not offering any details, so this is as good an answer as you're going to get (from me, at least).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hadoop is more for batch processing that high data access. You should have a look at some NoSQL systems, like document oriented databases. Hard to answer without knowing what your data is like.

The number one rule to NoSQL design is to define your query scenarios first. Once you really understand how you want to query the data then you can look into the various NoSQL solutions out there. The default unit of distribution is key. Therefore you need to remember that you need to be able to split your data between your node machines effectively otherwise you will end up with a horizontally scalable system with all the work still being done on one node (albeit better queries depending on the case).

You also need to think back to CAP theorem, most NoSQL databases are eventually consistent (CP or AP) while traditional Relational DBMS are CA. This will impact the way you handle data and creation of certain things, for example key generation can be come trickery. Obviously files in a folder are a bit different.

Also remember than in some systems such as HBase there is no indexing concept (I'm gussing you have file indexing setup on this windows FS document store). All your indexes will need to be built by your application logic and any updates and deletes will need to be managed as such. With Mongo you can actually create indexes on fields and query them relatively quickly, there is also the possibility to integrate Solr with Mongo. You don’t just need to query by ID in Mongo like you do in HBase which is a column family (aka Google BigTable style database) where you essentially have nested key-value pairs.

So once again it comes to your data, what you want to store, how you plan to store it, and most importantly how you want to access it. The Lily project looks very promising. THe work I am involved with we take a large amount of data from the web and we store it, analyse it, strip it down, parse it, analyse it, stream it, update it etc etc. We dont just use one system but many which are best suited to the job at hand. For this process we use different systems at different stages as it gives us fast access where we need it, provides the ability to stream and analyse data in real-time and importantly, keep track of everything as we go (as data loss in a prod system is a big deal) . I am using Hadoop, HBase, Hive, MongoDB, Solr, MySQL and even good old text files. Remember that to productionize a system using these technogies is a bit harder than installing Oracle on a server, some releases are not as stable and you really need to do your testing first. At the end of the day it really depends on the level of business resistance and the mission-critical nature of your system.

Another path that no one thus far has mentioned is NewSQL - i.e. Horizontally scalable RDBMSs... There are a few out there like MySQL cluster (i think) and VoltDB which may suit your cause.But again depending on your data (are the files word docs or text docs with info about products, invoices or instruments or something)...

Again it comes to understanding your data and the access patterns, NoSQL systems are also Non-Rel i.e. non-relational and are there for better suit to non-relational data sets. If your data is inherently relational and you need some SQL query features that really need to do things like Cartesian products (aka joins) then you may well be better of sticking with Oracle and investing some time in indexing, sharding and performance tuning.

My advice would be to actually play around with a few different systems. Look at;

**MongoDB** - Document - CP

**CouchDB** - Document - AP

**Cassandra** - Column Family - Available & Partition Tolerant (AP)

**VoltDB** - A really good looking product, a relation database that is distributed and might work for your case (may be an easier move). They also seem to provide enterprise support which may be more suited for a prod env (i.e. give business users a sense of security).

Any way thats my 2c. Playing around with the systems is really the only way your going to find out what really works for your case.

Comment: Great answer can you give any resourse for database        as data engineering prospect for begginner how can some one learn these things ?

Answer (score 0):

HDFS does not sound to be right solution. It is optimized for massive parralel processing of the data and not to be general purpose file system. 
Specifically it has following limitations making it probabbly bad choice: 
a) It is sensitive to the number of files. Practical limit  should be about dozens of millions of files.  
b) The files are read only, and can only be appended, but not edited. It is fine for analytical data processing but might not suite your need. 
c) It has single point of failure - namenode. So its reliability is limited.

If you need system with comparable scalability, but not sensitive to number of files I would suggest OpenStack's Swift. It also does not have SPOF.

Comment: a) is correct, b) can be simulated by a delete followed by a write, c) does no longer hold: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you can buy a NAS storage.  May be EMS isilon kind of product you can consider.

Hadoop HDFS is not for file storage. It is storage to processing the data (for reports, analytics..)

NAS is for file sharing

SAN is more for a database

http://www.slideshare.net/jabramo/emc-sanoverviewpresentation

Declaration: I am not a EMC person, so you can consider any product. I just used EMC for reference.